# p:tooltip direction

Tags: attributes, primefaces, tooltip

Is there any attribute for p:tooltip for direction as we get with rich:tooltip ? I essentially want my tooltip to show up at top right of an image. Not sure how to do that.  The number of attributes present for p:tooltip seem to be very limited. Following is the code for richfaces.

```xml
<h:commandLink value="Simple Link" id="link">
<rich:toolTip followMouse="true" direction="top-right" mode="ajax" value="#{bean.toolTipContent}" horizontalOffset="5" 
    verticalOffset="5" layout="block">
    <f:facet name="defaultContent">
        <f:verbatim>DEFAULT TOOLTIP CONTENT</f:verbatim>
    </f:facet>
</rich:toolTip>
```

Comment: There is none but feel free to create a feature request in PF issue tracker, it is quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be something for you? http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/tooltip/customizedTooltips.jsf;jsessionid=14y1z1yedm21t910h6zonwboq

Primefaces ext has a really neat tooltip imo.